# Tomograpy 3D reconstruction

Tags: matlab, stl, 3d-reconstruction, tomography-reconstruction

I have to do a project for school and I have no idea where to start from. I need to make a 3D reconstruction from the images you get after doing a tomography.
Also, after the image will be reconstructed i need to provide a tool so the user can slice the organ as he wants and so he can see the section he made.

Any help would be really apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to do some research and reading yourself, and then come back with a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Radon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/radon.html) function & [co](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/fanbeam.html) this is very likely what you will need to use. And see also this [book](http://www.slaney.org/pct/pct-toc.html) (a must have reference).

Answer (score 2):

A very quick Googling led me to [this page](http://www.biochem.mpg.de/baumeister/tom_e/started_new/index.html). A tomography toolbox for MATLAB.